# Flutter + auth0 embedded login page implementation (without universal login redirect)

Tags: flutter, authentication, flutter-dependencies, auth0

I am making an flutter app where I need a login. I chose to use auth0 but the flutter implementation uses only auth0 sdk where there is redirect to universal login page in native browser. I don't want that. I need to make my custom login page and fetch details in flutter and send that to auth0 for authorization. How can I can make this possible.

Thanks in advance.

I am tired of looking solutions and code snippets online. I couldn't do it on my own.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I am using auth0 to authenticate users to my flutter app, but auth0 provides their universal login. But I don't want to use their universal login want to use my flutter UI instead.

I tried setting up a node server, and after that, I created a user using email and password. But now I want to add google sign in too. But without using auth0 universal login UI.

I want a sign-in with a Google button, and when I press it, it will show the Google sign-in popup and store that data into the auth0 without a password. How can I do that?

Answer (score -2):

If you are using auth0 and dont want to use the auth0_flutter sdk, use this package: https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_appauth. And call your application‘s authorize endpoint with the grant type authorizatio code.

For a complete example follow this tutoriel: https://auth0.com/blog/amp/flutter-authentication-authorization-with-auth0-part-1-adding-authentication-to-an-app/

Comment: Hi Klaus, please do not post answers which are only links. If the link contains salient information, by all means use the link as a reference, but your answer should contain enough information to still be useful if the link fails.